# Will Java/Android garbage collector clean member variables in AsyncTask post cancel?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, garbage-collection

Will the garbage collector collect the member variables of a sub class when the super class is null'ed? And would the answer be any different if we are speaking about two threads, one running the super class while the second is running the sub class?

As for Android, if the AsyncTask is done and I drop the reference of it from my activity, would that cascade down to cleaning all the member variables in AsyncTask, or do I have to manually do that?

Lastly, can I assume that the AsyncTask thread is closed and deleted after the execution of `onPostExecute` or after it being cancelled for API's prior to 3?

Thanks in advance, Cheers.

CODE:

```
public class class1 {
    public class class2 extends AsyncTask<void, void, void>{
        Object object;

        class2(){
            object = new Object();
        }
    }
    class2 _class2;

    class1(){
        _class2 = new class2();
    }
}
```

Then I declare a variable of type `class1 _class1 = new class1()` somewhere, then after executing it and being done with it, I set `_class1 = null`, would that automatically drop the reference of the member `object` and collect it by the GC?

Comment: A class isn't "nulled" - nor is an object. A *variable* can be set to null, but that's very different. It would help if you could provide actual code instead of just describing it.

Comment: I think you're talking about class fields instead of subclass /superclass

Comment: Jon, I meant the reference. Tala, I am talking about both actually. I just edited the question with brief codes.